# Object not found - Netbeans always give error like so

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, web, error-handling

When ever i try to run a php class from my netbeans i always get this error. I do not even have any clue what so ever because my Apache web server and mysql both is running that you can see in the picture, so why every time it is giving this error.
[image]

Can anyone please help me with this. I have tried almost everything couldn't find out the problem.

Comment: First try by executing one sample php file with phpinfo(). Let us know here what error you will face..

Comment: it is the same error ...Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

Comment: Same issue here.